Product of quotient map $p: X \to Y$ and identity $Id_Z$ is a quotient map when $Z$ is compact and Hausdorff
Let $X,Y,Z$ be topological spaces where $Z$ is compact and Hausdorff. Let $p: X \to Y$ be a quotient map. I want to show that $$p \times Id_z: X \times Z \to Y \times Z: (x,z) \mapsto (p(x),z)$$ is a quotient map.

My attempt
I need to show that for an open $(p \times Id_z)^{-1}[U]$, we have that U is open. I try to show this by finding an open neighbourhood V for any $([x],y) \in U$ which is contained in $U$. Take $(x,y) \in (p \times Id_z)^{-1}[{([X],y)}]$. Then we know there exists opens $U_x$ and $U_z$ such that $(x,y) \in U_x \times U_z \subseteq (p \times Id_z)^{-1}[U]$ I'm trying to show that $p(U_x) \times U_z$ is open in $Y \times Z$.
How to use that $Z$ is Hausdorff and compact? Do I need to use that $Z$ is normal?
Thank you!

Welcome to the site. Are you looking for hints, or a full solution? This is a "well-known" thing and should be covered in most classical topology texts and probably also on this website before, so for full solutions you can check there e.g. in Brown's "topology and groupoids" (available online)

Assume that $(p\times \text{Id}_Z)^{-1}(U)$ is open and let $(p(x), z)\in U$. Then $(x, z)\in (p\times \text{Id}_Z)^{-1}(U)$ and we can find an open neighbourhood $W$ of $z$ such that $\{x\}\times W\subseteq (p\times \text{Id}_Z)^{-1}(U)$. Since $Z$ is locally compact Hausdorff there is an open neighbourhood $W'$ of $z$ with compact closure such that $\overline{W'}\subseteq W$. Slices of open sets are open so for each $z\in \overline{W'}$ we have
$$(p\times \text{Id}_Z)^{-1}(U)\cap \big(X\times \{z\} \big)=V_z\times \{z\}$$
for some saturated open neighbourhood $V_z$ of $x$. Let $V=\bigcap\limits_{z\in \overline{W'}} V_z$. Then $x\in V$ and $V \times \overline{W'}\subseteq (p\times \text{Id}_Z)^{-1}(U)$. Moreover $V$ is saturated and the tube lemma implies that $V$ is open. Therefore $p(V)\times W'$ is an open neighbourhood of $(p(x), z)$ contained in $U$. Hence $U$ is open.

I understand everything except the implication "$V$ is saturated and the tube lemma imply that $V$ is open"

By a set $A\subseteq X$ being saturated I mean that $p^{-1}(p(A))=A$, more intuitively $A$ is a union of equivalence classes under the equivalence relation induced by $p$. I'm using that an intersection of saturated sets is saturated.
To see that $V$ is open, let $x\in V$. Then ${x}\times \overline{W'}\subseteq (p\times \text{Id}_Z)^{-1}(U)$ and the tube lemma gives an open neighbourhood $B$ of $x$ so that $B\times \overline{W'}\subseteq (p\times \text{Id}_Z)^{-1}(U)$. Then $B\subseteq V$. Since $x\in V$ was arbitrary, $V$ is open

Ah yes clear! 1 last question: why is $V_z$ saturated?

Note that $x\in V_z \Leftrightarrow (p(x), z)\in U$. In particular, if $x\in V_z$ and $p(x)=p(x')$ then $x'\in V_z$.

So in the end you actually only needed $Z$ to be locally compact Hausdorff
